# Unsplash images fetched using Paging3 are not showing in LazyColumn

Tags: dagger-hilt, android-paging, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I'm trying to follow an online course to fetch images from Unsplash to view these images inside a LazyColumn, and I also followed all guidelines inside Unsplash Documentation. But the images or other data inside the LazyColumn are not showing. Only the app bar and background are visible.
I will add below some code for clarification.

build.gradle (:app-side) to get API_KEY from "properties".

```
val properties = Properties()
try {
    properties.load(FileInputStream(rootProject.file("gradle.properties")))
} catch (e: Exception) {
    logger.warn("Properties not Found!")
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
      ----
      buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "" + properties["API_KEY"])
    }
}
```

//UnsplashAPI.kt

```
interface UnsplashApi {
    @Headers("Authorization: Client-ID ${BuildConfig.API_KEY}")
    @GET("/photos")
    suspend fun getAllImages(
        @Query("page") page: Int,
        @Query("per_page") perPage: Int
    ): List<UnsplashImage>

    @Headers("Authorization: Client-ID ${BuildConfig.API_KEY}")
    @GET("/search/photos")
    suspend fun searchImages(
        @Query("query") query: String,
        @Query("per_page") perPage: Int
    ): List<UnsplashImage>
}
```

ListContent.kt

```
@ExperimentalCoilApi
@Composable
fun ListContent(items: LazyPagingItems<UnsplashImage>) {
    Log.d("Error", items.loadState.toString())
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(all = 12.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
    ) {
        items(count = items.itemCount,
            key = items.itemKey { unsplashImage ->
                unsplashImage.id
            }
        ) { index ->
            items[index]?.let { UnsplashItem(unsplashImage = it) }
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalCoilApi
@Composable
fun UnsplashItem(unsplashImage: UnsplashImage) {
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(unsplashImage.urls.regular)
            .crossfade(durationMillis = 1000)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder).build())
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable {
                val browserIntent = Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("https://unsplash.com/@${unsplashImage.user.userName}?utm_source=DemoApp&utm_medium=referral")
                )
                startActivity(context, browserIntent, null)
            }
            .height(300.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = "Unsplash Image",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(40.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .alpha(ContentAlpha.medium),
            color = Color.Black
        ) {}
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(40.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 6.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Text(
                text = buildAnnotatedString {
                    append("Photo by ")
                    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Black)) {
                        append(unsplashImage.user.userName)
                    }
                    append(" on Unsplash")
                },
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 15.sp,
                maxLines = 1,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
            )
            LikeCounter(
                modifier = Modifier.weight(3f),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_heart),
                likes = "${unsplashImage.likes}"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

HomeScreen.kt

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoilApi::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavHostController,
               homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val getAllImages = homeViewModel.getAllImages.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            HomeTopBar(onSearchClicked = {
                navController.navigate(Screen.Search.route)
            })
        },
        content = {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues = it)) {}
            ListContent(items = getAllImages)
        }
    )
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a simple search in my code, I realized that I forgot to add this annotation: @SerialName("The Actual Parameter Name In Your Json File"), if the used name is different.

```
@Serializable
data class User(
    @SerialName("links")
    @Embedded
    val userLinks: UserLinks,
    val username: String
)
```